# How to parse json array in kusto query language

Tags: azure-log-analytics, kql

How to parse json array in kusto query language.
I have an output column which is having value in JSON array format as shown below. I Need to parse it to get values in form of two columns.

```
{"count": 14
"value": [
        {
            "Total_Record_Count": 16608,
            "date": "2021-03-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "Total_Record_Count": 27254,
            "date": "2021-02-24T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "Total_Record_Count": 6,
            "date": "2021-02-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "Total_Record_Count": 26964,
            "date": "2021-01-15T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "Total_Record_Count": 134516,
            "date": "2020-12-18T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "Total_Record_Count": 27345,
            "date": "2020-12-16T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "Total_Record_Count": 521,
            "date": "2020-12-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "Total_Record_Count": 4,
            "date": "2020-11-02T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "Total_Record_Count": 6,
            "date": "2020-10-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "Total_Record_Count": 1,
            "date": "2020-09-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "Total_Record_Count": 3,
            "date": "2020-08-03T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "Total_Record_Count": 18,
            "date": "2020-07-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "Total_Record_Count": 18754,
            "date": "2020-06-16T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "Total_Record_Count": 4451898,
            "date": "2020-06-08T00:00:00Z"
        }
    ]}
```

How can I achieve it using output column name instead of using full json array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please see example below that uses mv-expand operator for breaking array into rows.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mvexpandoperator

```
print d = dynamic(
{"count": 14,
"value": [
        {
            "Total_Record_Count": 16608,
            "date": "2021-03-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "Total_Record_Count": 27254,
            "date": "2021-02-24T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "Total_Record_Count": 6,
            "date": "2021-02-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "Total_Record_Count": 26964,
            "date": "2021-01-15T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "Total_Record_Count": 134516,
            "date": "2020-12-18T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "Total_Record_Count": 27345,
            "date": "2020-12-16T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "Total_Record_Count": 521,
            "date": "2020-12-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "Total_Record_Count": 4,
            "date": "2020-11-02T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "Total_Record_Count": 6,
            "date": "2020-10-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "Total_Record_Count": 1,
            "date": "2020-09-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "Total_Record_Count": 3,
            "date": "2020-08-03T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "Total_Record_Count": 18,
            "date": "2020-07-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "Total_Record_Count": 18754,
            "date": "2020-06-16T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "Total_Record_Count": 4451898,
            "date": "2020-06-08T00:00:00Z"
        }
    ]})
| project Value = d.['value'] 
| mv-expand Value
| project Count = tolong(Value.['Total_Record_Count']), Date = todatetime(Value.['date'])
```

| Count | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 4451898 | 2020-06-08 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 18754 | 2020-06-16 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 18 | 2020-07-01 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 3 | 2020-08-03 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 1 | 2020-09-01 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 6 | 2020-10-01 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 4 | 2020-11-02 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 521 | 2020-12-01 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 27345 | 2020-12-16 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 134516 | 2020-12-18 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 26964 | 2021-01-15 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 6 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 27254 | 2021-02-24 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 16608 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00.0000000 |

Comment: Thanks Alexander. Its working when I use complete json array in print d = dynamic(pasting json array here). But I am trying to use column name where I am getting this JSON array value as an output. I could not find the way to do that.

Comment: It should work the same. If the column type is string and not dynamic - you can use parse_json(ColumnName) function to convert it to dynamic column

Comment: How to modify the query if we want to sum all the 'Total_Record_Count'